# Could a failure of condensed inner speech be linked to slowed cognition?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, hallucinations

Could a failure of "condensed inner speech" be linked to slowed cognition? It is a type of inner voice, and as conceptualized by Fernyhough it

> involves the capacity to think in terms of pure meaning without the
>   need to put thoughts into words in order to grasp the meaning of the
>   thought.

I'm just wondering whether, either in healthy or psychopathological cognition, condensed inner speech has been shown to be more difficult when thinking is slowed for some reason, such as psychotropic medication. I have read that people tend to use expanded (as opposed to condensed) inner speech when under *stress*.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a study trying to test your idea. I suppose your hypothesis could be tested by comparing the results Varieties of Inner Speech Questionnaire (VISQ) on the expanded/condensed dimension of participants with induced slower condition to a control group.

McCarthy-Jones & Fernyhough (2011) studied the correlations between the dimensions and psycho-pathological variables. They found the expanded/condensed dimension was not predictive of psychopathology.

**References**

McCarthy-Jones, S., & Fernyhough, C. (2011). The varieties of inner speech: Links between quality of inner speech and psychopathological variables in a sample of young adults. *Consciousness and Cognition, 20*(4), 1586–1593. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.concog.2011.08.005